# How can I hide the text Using zend form in zend studio

Tags: php, zend-framework

//User can see this textfield well i want it to be hidden from user

```
 $form=new Zend_Form;

    $this->setMethod ( 'post' );

    $purchaseid=$this->createElement('text', 'purchaseid');  

    $this->addElement($purchaseid);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a hidden field, you can do this:

```
$purchaseid=$this->createElement('hidden', 'purchaseid');
```